# Class that changes another class's object state depending on both subtypes

Tags: design-patterns

This is a homework question.

I have the following problem: I need to create a system that can simulate the way a landlord taxes or charges a tenant, according to the type of landlord and the type of tenant. The landlord can be a Low Class landlord (manages a crappy apartment building), a Middle Class landlord (manages a so-so building) and a High Class landlord (manages a top-class building). The tenant can be an Irresponsible tenant (pays with several months of delay) or a Responsible tenant (pays on time).

There is a fixed tariff according to the kind of landlord, and there's a penalty or a benefit given according to the kind of tenant and the kind of landlord: an Irresponsible tenant will be charged extra, and the Responsible will be given some bonus for paying early or whatever, but this only applies if he lives in a building managed by a High Class landlord or a Middle Class landlord. Tenant is supposed to have an attribute that stores the money it has to pay in rent.

I diagrammed this problem this way:

- A Landlord abstract class, with the following concrete classes that inherit from it: High Class, Low Class and Middle Class.
- A Tenant abstract class, with Irresponsible and Responsible concrete descendants.

My problem is how do I implement a method to charge the tenant? I proposed the following: the Landlord class defines a virtual method called chargeTheTenant(), that takes a parameter of class Tenant and charges it according to the type of tenant it is. The problem is that for this I'd have to use reflection to find out what kind of Tenant the Landlord class has, and I'm told I have to try not to use reflection, and that I should search for design patterns to solve this.

What design pattern I should look into to avoid using reflection in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a scenario for the Strategy pattern. Anyways, it something like this (C# ahead)

```
public interface IChargeRent
{
      void Chanrge(Tenant tenant);
}

public class HighClassPropertyRentCollector:IChargeRent
{
     //we assume this object contains or it gets the tarrifs

     public void Charge(Tenant tenant)
     {
          if (tenant.IsIrresponsible) { //apply penalty
              }
             else{ //whatever }
     }
}


public class MiddleClassPropertyRentCollector:HighClassPropertyRentCollector {}

public class LowClassPropertyRentCollector:IChargeRent
{
     public void Charge(Tenant tenant) {

      }
 }

   public interface ICanChargeRent
   {
       PropertyClassType PropetyLevel {get;}
   }

   public class Landlord:ICanChargeRent { }

 //in another class
 public static IChargeRent GetRentCollector(ICanChargeRent ll)
 {
       //switch on PropertyLevel and instantiate the corresponding rent charger
  }
```

Middle landlords have, for now, the same behaviour as the high class landlords so that's why I inherit from high class landlords, however that could change so its better to have an explicit rent charging strategy for each landlord. Same for low class landlords.

If there is a certain way to determine the quality of the tenant, then each will get injected a service which will provide that funcitonality. And because the rent charging behaviour is encapsulated their own classes, you can change it without needing to change the Landlord.

The reason my solution is different from your proposal is that charging rent is not really part of what defines a Landlord (yes, I know how it sounds) but a use case of a landlord. After all, if the landlord hires a property manager and tells him to charge rent, does the definition of a landlord changes? Not so much.

Even in this scenario 99% of the code I wrote works unchanged. You only need to make the PropertyManager implement ICanChargeRent while removing the interface from the Landlord. And we can come up with an even more maintainable solution (requiring less changes) if we know more details about the domain.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, the Tenant abstract class might be a sign of over abstraction. If you use only a single Tenant class with method **IsIrresponsible**(), landlord can directly make decision based on the return of this method.

If you insist to use the abstract Tenant class, just make the **IsIrresponsible**() function virtual. And always return true inside the *IrresponsibleTenant* subclass, and return false in the *ResponsibleTenant* subclass. But personally I don't think it's worthy.